# Subspace proximity

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two rank-$k$ projection matrices $\Pi_1, \Pi_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (i.e. $\Pi_1 = \Pi_1^2$ and $\Pi_2 = \Pi_2^2$), what is the best function $c_{n,r}$ such that $\|\Pi_1 - \Pi_2 \|^2_F \leq c \| \Pi_1 (\Pi_1 - \Pi_2) \Pi_1 \|^2_F$?

When $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ span orthogonal subspaces, it is easy to see that $c =2$. For random projector matrices, $c_{n,r}\leq2$ still seems to hold computationally. For small perturbations of random projectors, $c_{n,r}$ appears to be much larger than $n$.

Comment: There seems to be a misprint somewhere: if you take projections to two very close lines in $\mathbb R^2$, the constant blows up as written, doesn't it?